# Issues creating a php shuffle from outputted db results

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, shuffle

I'm attempting to create a PHP shuffle when a submit button is pressed. I have not seen any examples like what I am trying to do as I am going to be using the outputted results for other things. As of right now this code is broken and I cannot get past a parse error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'` for this line...

`foreach ($shuffle_row) {`

What am I doing wrong in my approach?

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "ROOT", "", "DB");
$shuffle_run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group`= 3");
if( $shuffle_numrows > 0) {
    while($shuffle_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shuffle_run)){
        $shuffle_id = $shuffle_row['id'];
        $shuffle_firstname = $suffle_row['firstname'];
        $shuffle_lastname = $shuffle_row['lastname'];
        $shuffle_username = $shuffle_row['username'];
        $shuffle_email = $shuffle_row['email'];

        if ($shuffle_firstname == true) {
            echo $shuffle_firstname . $shuffle_lastname;
        } else {
            echo "No users have been registered yet.";
        };
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['shuffle']))  {
    $shuffle_row = array();
    shuffle($shuffle_row);
    foreach ($shuffle_row) {
        echo $shuffle_firstname . " " . $shuffle_lastname;
    }
}
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Shuffle" name="shuffle">
```

Comment: I have errors in my question...how is it a duplicate??

Comment: I took that out. See my comment below. In my text editor I forgot to delete some funky things.

Comment: You set `$shuffle_row` at the top of your code and then reset it with `$shuffle_row = array()`?

Comment: You still also have a floating semicolon in your code `};` after your `else{...}` statement.

Comment: I wasn't sure how else to generate the array. I'm pretty new to php

Comment: I cleaned up your code and noticed that you have an extra `}` at the end as well as the extra semicolon after the close parenthesis: `};` which you should remove. Try fixing those issues and run your code again.

Comment: I took out the semi colon at the end of this ... `echo "No users have been registered yet.";
        };` and the same error is still showing.